# signing a document with existing digital signature

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, itext7

I have the code below that add a **placeholder** for signature and write pre-sign file and then get a hash from it.

**extra explanation:** (and after that I sent the **hash** to the client(where the private key is) to sign the hash and finally after that i will add the signed hash to pdf.)
**Problem:** when I try to sign a pdf without the digital signature on it , this approach work perfect but if I want to sign a pdf that already has been signed by other people it will break the first signature.

```
    public PadesDigestRes digest(PadesDigestReq req) throws Exception {
        try {
            // create result object
            PadesDigestRes result = new PadesDigestRes();

            // generate id for pdf document
            String fileId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

            // read pdf from base64 document
            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader pdfReader = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader(new ByteArrayInputStream(Base64Utils.decodeFromString(req.getBase64Document())));

            // create destination file output stream
            File file = new File(TEMP_DIR + fileId + ".pdf");

            // create stamper to add properties to the pdf document
            PdfStamper pdfStamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(pdfReader, null, '\0', file, true);

            // read previous signatures from pdf document
            ArrayList<String> signatureNames = pdfStamper.getAcroFields().getSignatureNames();

            // check if there is no signature field on the pdf document
            // then add new page at the end of the pdf document to add new signature field
            if (signatureNames.size() == 0) {
                com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader tempReader = pdfStamper.getReader();
                int numberOfPages = tempReader.getNumberOfPages();
                pdfStamper.insertPage(numberOfPages + 1, tempReader.getPageSize(1));
            }

            // get signature appearance && set required properties
            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfSignatureAppearance signatureAppearance = pdfStamper.getSignatureAppearance();
            //read the user certificate 
            X509Certificate certificate = PadesUtil.getX509CertificateFromBase64String(req.getBase64Certificate());
            signatureAppearance.setCertificate(certificate);
            signatureAppearance.setReason("test");
            signatureAppearance.setLocation("Berlin");

            //read user data from certificate
            X500Name certificateName = PadesUtil.getX500NameByCertificate(certificate);
            RDN nationalCode = PadesUtil.getRDN(certificateName);
            String signDate = PadesUtil.generateSignDate();

            String signatureInfo = PadesUtil.generateSignatureStringInfo(signatureNames.size(), certificate, nationalCode, signDate);
            
            signatureAppearance.setLayer2Text(signatureInfo);
            signatureAppearance.setLayer4Text(signatureInfo);

            //building ui for the signature
            float width = pdfStamper.getReader().getPageSizeWithRotation(1).getWidth();
            int whoMany = (int) Math.floor(width / (150 + 25));
            int signatureIndex = signatureNames.size() + 1;
            float lowerLeftX = (((signatureIndex % whoMany) - 1) * 150 + 25) * signatureIndex;
            float lowerLeftY = (signatureIndex / whoMany) * 100 + 50;
            Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(lowerLeftX, lowerLeftY, 150, 100);
            
            
            String fieldName = PadesUtil.generateUserInfo(certificate);
            signatureAppearance.setVisibleSignature(rectangle, pdfStamper.getReader().getNumberOfPages(), fieldName);
            
            // set both digital and image signature on render mode
            signatureAppearance.setRenderingMode(PdfSignatureAppearance.RenderingMode.DESCRIPTION);

            // create signature container
            com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalBlankSignatureContainer external = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.ExternalBlankSignatureContainer(com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.ADOBE_PPKLITE, com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfName.ADBE_PKCS7_DETACHED);
            MakeSignature.signExternalContainer(signatureAppearance, external, 10000);

            // read generated document(pre-signed pdf with placeholder) from file and get hashable byte range
            PdfReader pdfReaderForHash = new PdfReader(TEMP_DIR + fileId + ".pdf");
            PdfDocument pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(pdfReaderForHash);
            SignatureUtil signatureUtil = new SignatureUtil(pdfDocument);
            PdfSignature pdfSignature = signatureUtil.getSignature(fieldName);

            if (pdfSignature == null) {
                throw (new com.itextpdf.kernel.PdfException("There is no field in the document with such name: {0}."))
                        .setMessageParams(new Object[]{fieldName});
            } else if (!signatureUtil.signatureCoversWholeDocument(fieldName)) {
                throw (new PdfException("Signature with name {0} is not the last. It doesn't cover the whole document."))
                        .setMessageParams(new Object[]{fieldName});
            } else {
                PdfArray byteRange = pdfSignature.getByteRange();
                long[] gaps = byteRange.toLongArray();
                IRandomAccessSource readerSource = pdfDocument.getReader().getSafeFile().createSourceView();
                InputStream data = new RASInputStream((new RandomAccessSourceFactory()).createRanged(readerSource, gaps));

                byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("./path/to/chain.p7b"));
                Certificate[] certificates = readCertificatesFromPKCS7(bytes);

                // create hash from whole document
                ExternalDigest digestBC = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.BouncyCastleDigest();
                String algorithm = DigestAlgorithms.SHA256;
                com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = new com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.PdfPKCS7(null, certificates, algorithm, null, digestBC, false);
                byte[] documentHash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digestBC.getMessageDigest(algorithm));
                byte[] authedAttrBytes = pkcs7.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(documentHash, null, null, MakeSignature.CryptoStandard.CMS);

                // set response fields
                result.setFileId(fileId);
                result.setBase64Pkcs7(Base64Utils.encodeToString(authedAttrBytes));
                result.setBase64DocumentDigest(Base64Utils.encodeToString(documentHash));

                return result;
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            log.warn("Could not read document with base64document value : " + e);
            throw new IOException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (DocumentException e) {
            log.warn("Could not create signature using pdfStamper : " + e);
            throw new DocumentException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (PdfException e) {
            log.warn(e.getMessage());
            throw new PdfException(e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            log.warn("Internal error : " + e);
            throw new Exception(e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

This is a error that i get from the Adobe Acrobat Reader"[image: the second signature is ok but it broke the first valid signature]

Comment: Do you have an example document? (Append mode is active so should be ok)

Comment: Indeed, please share an example before and after your code runs.

Comment: this is a pdf without any signature :
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1n61SomPOf7H9PmDhZwCt-TdwpUfEqU9K/view?usp=sharing
this is a pdf with first signature:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1mGHFhRbUDMhatea0nh7LNeHVaLKH-k9i/view?usp=share_link
after I sign this document for second time I got the error, this is the document after second signature:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AN7--YfHItqTlqqe3SvoGrG4JdjCX82T/view?usp=share_link

Comment: and this is the document after I run the above code on the document with one signature(the document with placeholder for the second signature ):
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1AN7--YfHItqTlqqe3SvoGrG4JdjCX82T/view?usp=share_link

Comment: You shared the same link twice.

Comment: Comparing one_signature.pdf and two_signature.pdf one sees that after adding the first signature but before adding the second one the PDF is processed in non-append mode. This appears not to happen in the code you show.

Comment: thanks @mkl . my understanding from your comment is that append mode is playing an important role in the process. I will check all my code for the possible non append mode.

Comment: @siamak *"my understanding from your comment is that append mode is playing an important role in the process"* - Indeed it does! Whenever you manipulate a PDF without using append mode, you garble all included digital signatures and time stamps.